# docker - how to determine which mount belongs to which image?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, docker-container, device-mapper

We use device mapper storage driver. 
This is probably more of a docker than k8s question.

Is there is a way to determine for example where this mount is coming from

> /opt/dsx/ibm-data-platform/docker/devicemapper/mnt/b1127f21d5fd96b2ac862624d80b928decc1d60b87ec64d98430f69f360d3cee/rootfs/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.39.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar

You see `devicemapper/mnt/b1127f21d5fd96b2ac862624d80b928decc1d60b87ec64d98430f69f360d3cee` as part of the path..

We use a commercial product that has 67 different images bundled in. 
One particular above has a very old Java .. we'd like to know which image that docker mount is coming from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can ask Docker for a list of containers that have that volume mounted:

`docker container ls --filter=volume=<name of volume>`

Comment: thanks. `sudo docker container ls --filter=volume=b1127f21d5fd96b2ac862624d80b928decc1d60b87ec64d98430f69f360d3cee` returns empty list.. can I use that volume uuid instead of volume name? docker/k8s is somewhat new to me . also `sudo docker volume ls | grep b1127f21d5fd96b2ac862624d80b928decc1d60b87ec64d98430f69f360d3cee` returns empty list.

Comment: Usually, the UUID.is the name. Does volume ls return anything,.without the grep

Comment: Yes, `docker volume ls` returns 6 lines, with `uuid`s for the `volume name` column.  Although `b1127f21d5fd96b2ac862624d80b928decc1d60b87ec64d98430f69f360d3cee` is not one of them. Notice that we use `device mapper` storage driver for dockers .. does it explain this?

Comment: The `rootfs` in the mnt would lead me to believe this may be an image ID rather than a volume. Try image ls.

Comment: `docker image ls` returns shorter ids like `9e1c85961ecd` that do not match to any of the `devicemapper/mnt/b1127f21d5fd96b2ac862624d80b928decc1d60b87ec64d98430f69f360d3cee` uuids..